# Why do all fluid particles crossing a point in a steadily flowing fluid have to follow the same path?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I came across the following lines in Resnick, Halliday, Krane's Fundamentals of Physics :

> In steady flow, the velocity **V** at a given point is constant in time. Consider a point *P* within the fluid. Since **V** at *P*  does not change in time in steady flow, every fluid particle arriving at *P* will pass on with the same speed in the same in the same direction. The motion of every particle passing through *P* thus follows the same path.

Now, the above statement does not have to be necessarily true. Consider the following scenario:
[image]

Two fluid particles **a** and **b** are passing through *P*. Since the two paths have the same tangent at *P*, the direction of their velocities will be the same at *P*. Their speeds can also be set to be the same at *P* ( perhaps by stating that the two particles have have the same uniform speed *u* ). Yet, as shown in the figure, the particles don't follow the same path.

How can this be explained?

A similar question has been asked here:

[Can two streamlines in a fluid be tangential to each other not crossing each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320736/can-two-streamlines-in-a-fluid-be-tangential-to-each-other-not-crossing-each-oth?rq=1)

But only the possibility is sought and addressed (atleast at the time of asking my question). So, what is the reason?

PS : The two particles need not be at P at the same instant. Also, I don't think its possible for two incompressible particles to be at the same point at the same instant.

Comment: At the instant when both particles are at $P$, why does one go upward on a curved trajectory while the other remains on a straight line?

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. I forgot to mention that the two particles need not be at P at the same instant. The question just addresses the individual paths of the two particles.

Comment: Even so, is it not true that the two paths have the same tangent at P? I am therefore unable to understand why one shouldn't go upward on a curved trajectory while the other remains on a straight line. What exactly is wrong with that?

Comment: "In steady flow" means that the velocity field doesn't change with time.

Comment: The two lines you drew do have the same tangent at P, but they can't be streamlines, because streamlines cannot intersect.  Essentially, if a particle starts at $P$, then its trajectory precisely follows the velocity field and is unambiguous.  Two intersecting streamlines would imply that a particle starting at the intersection point somehow "decides" which path to follow based on something not contained in the fluid equations.

Comment: -1 Why doesn't the comment by Deep in the similar question answer your question? In steady flow it is not possible for trajectories to touch or cross.

Comment: @sammy gerbil In Deep's comment, it has only been said that it is impossible for two stream lines to pass through a single point, without a reason being given. I seek reason :).

Comment: @J. Murray . well I did not interpret intersection to mean both touching and cutting of two curves. However as you clearly pointed out the path starting from a point for a fluid particle should be unambiguous. That pretty much cleared the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I expanded the two comments into an answer and provided 2 reasons.

Comment: @sammy gerbil. Sorry, I was not aware of that. I went through your answer. It  answered my question too. Thanks.

Comment: *The two particles need not be at P at the same instant. Also, I don't think its possible for two incompressible particles to be at the same point at the same instant.* If streamlines overlap or intersect, then two fluid particles (one from each streamline) will be at P at the same time. This is because the fluid is continuous : there are no gaps between particles. Even if the particles are compressible it is not possible for two particles to occupy the same point at the same time. They must be a finite distance apart.